# forcing iOS alerts to stay inside the system pull-down menu

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm testing an iPhone app before appstore submission.

However, the push notification alerts only come up as a alert banner and then roll away after 1 second, BUT never stay in the system pull-down menu.

Why do alert badges stay for other apps? Is it because they are already appstore approved?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disposition of alert messages is configurable by the user by application. Is Notification Center enabled for your application in settings on the device? I suspect that Banner Notifications are enabled but Notification Center is not.

Comment: Notification Center for our app is ON. And always has been even for our pre-Appstore app.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: also, why are other apps automatically able to (with no manual setting) and our pre-appstore one is not

Comment: The only caveat I'm aware of is that I believe that an app will not appear in the notification center *settings* until the app has actually sent a notification. At least that used to be the case, that behavior may not be the default anymore. There's not programmatic way to have the application specify which notification methods are valid, it's entirely configurable on the device. Can you add the code where you set up and handle your notifications in your app?